# Responsive Column Img and Paragraph

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a website where I want the image on the left and a paragraph on the right. Then when the screen is smaller I want the image on the top and the paragraph on the bottom.

It's simple and i've done it before but for some reason it's not working. I've Googled/looked at other examples but can't seem to identify the issue. Can someone help? I'm sure it's something simple i'm just not seeing.

HTML:

```
  <h1>About</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" id="img-about">
  <p id="text-about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias perspiciatis asperiores in aliquid repudiandae blanditiis recusandae molestiae nemo itaque inventore velit illum vel voluptatibus, eveniet repellat facilis consectetur veritatis deleniti explicabo ducimus! Debitis numquam unde necessitatibus esse sed. Earum accusamus itaque autem reiciendis aliquam laboriosam sint rem illo explicabo culpa?</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#about-img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#text-about {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 800){
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: changing that to (max-width: 800px) should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query is missing the unit of measurement.

Change

```
@media (max-width: 800){
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

to

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG yes that was it. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the unit for your media queries.

```
 @media (max-width: 800px)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#about-img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#text-about {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
 <h1>About</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/586744/pexels-photo-586744.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="image" id="img-about">
  <p id="text-about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias perspiciatis asperiores in aliquid repudiandae blanditiis recusandae molestiae nemo itaque inventore velit illum vel voluptatibus, eveniet repellat facilis consectetur veritatis deleniti explicabo ducimus! Debitis numquam unde necessitatibus esse sed. Earum accusamus itaque autem reiciendis aliquam laboriosam sint rem illo explicabo culpa?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add 'px' for the media query.
800px, then it will work.